# Как прочитать очень большой текстовый файл?

Tags: c#, файлы, текст

Имеется текстовый файл содержащий всего одну строку, но размер файла 1 Гб. Каким образом прочитать файл целиком? `File.ReadAllLines`, `File.ReadLines`, `File.ReadAllText` завершаются с ошибкой о недостаточности памяти. На выходе нужно получить строку (объект типа `string`) с содержимым из файла. Файл одно строчный, но строка очень длинная.

Comment: дополните вопрос необходимой информацией. Сейчас ответить на ваш вопрос однозначно невозможно. Для чего вам прочитать весь файл? что хотите получить на выходе? и т.д.

Comment: File.ReadLines — правильный путь. Ваша ошибка после — например, если вы накапливаете строки в памяти.

Comment: Файл с бинарными данными или текст?

Comment: Текстовый файл, строка всего одна.

Comment: @VladD так похоже ему в память и надо прочитать. у меня была похожая задачка, я читал стрим и бил файл на части по 10Мб, ибо даже 200МБ моя машина не вывозила

Comment: Тогда никак. Если вам нужно в память загрузить строку, которая больше объёма доступной памяти, тогда гаиньки. Читайте по символам.

Comment: Доступной памяти еще 5 Гб сверху. Проблема в библиотеке, которая задействуются при вызове функций File.ReadAllLines и т.п.

Comment: @TiFix на машинную память не обращайте внимания, у меня например доступной около 20Г, но прочитать файлик размером в гиг даже ей трудновато

Comment: Попробовал использовать FileStream, но ошибка та же OutOfMemory Exception.                                                                                                 string str = "";
            FileStream fstream = new FileStream("document.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            using (var sr = new StreamReader(fstream))
            {
                str = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }

Comment: Если задача стоит "обработать строку", то открываете stream и не ReadToEnd, а читаете и на лету обрабатываете. Если же задача "загрузить в память", то можно создать массив нужной длины и потом заполнить его или посимвольно или блоками и тем самым избежать накладных расходов обычного чтения, что убивают доступную память.

Comment: Физическая память ничего не значит в системах с пейджингом (например, Windows), заканчивается у вас виртуальная память. Ну или вы упираетесь в ограничение на размер объекта.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нашел подробное описание причин этой ошибки вот здесь: [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809514/outofmemoryexception-when-i-read-500mb-filestream).
Всем спасибо за помощь, в данный момент использую такой код:

```
char[] buffer = new char[104857600];
string text = "";
FileStream fstream = new FileStream("document.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
using (var sr = new StreamReader(fstream))
{
    int bytesRead = 0;
    while ((bytesRead = sr.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
        text = new string(buffer);
        // обработка текста
    }
}
```

Comment: У вас действительно xml? Тогда не лучше ли применить XmlReader?

Comment: Не xml, простой текст, без тэгов, расширение не соответствуют содержимому. Поправил пример кода.

Answer (score 1):

Соберите приложение под AnyCPU и снимите в свойствах проекта чекбокс "Prefer 32 Bit". Пропишите в конфиге приложения

```xml
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <gcAllowVeryLargeObjects enabled="true" />
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Это снимет большую часть ограничений по памяти, и вашу строку можно будет спокойно прочитать целиком.

Comment: Мне кажется, нужно скорее пнуть автора в сторону поточной обработки. Тем более, на 32-битной системе будет всё равно проблема.

Comment: @VladD возможно. но вытаскивать из него детали о настоящей задаче не хочется. Пусть сам осознает, что подходит к решению задачи не с той стороны :)

Comment: И в бесконечный цикл это. )

Answer (score 0):

Используй значит MemoryMappedFile.